# Symfony 4 - Two-dimensional translations

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I am currently facing the need of two-dimensional translations. The concept being arbitrary named by myself, let me explain my need from example.

Let's assume a website available in **English** and **French**.
Let's assume this website is a game where players can play **Human** or **Dwarf**.

Players have war units. The names of the war units can be translated into **english** or **french**, but then also into **human** or **dwarf**. For example, a distance unit for the dwarves would be called a **crossbowman**, while it would be called an **archer** for humans, still being the same unit in database though.

To simplify things, here is a JSON representation of the described mapping:

```
"units": {
    "english": {
        "human": "Archer",
        "dwarf": "Crossbowman"
    },
    "french": {
        "human": "Archer",
        "dwarf": "Arbalétrier"
    }
}
```

So while inspecting his distance units, a french dwarf player would see *Arbalétrier*, and an english dwarf player would see *Archer*. I would call this a two-dimensional translation.

Many solutions exist, a lot come to my mind. I could multiply translation keys for the same entity (`unit.dist.dwarf`, `unit.dist.human`). I could write a custom Service and process a second translation based upon a stored JSON mapping. All of this would work, but it would be kinda makeshift job.

Is there an elegant and Symfonycal way of achieving this?

Comment: Why would you need two dimensions? both a crossbowman and an archer are units, it just so happens that the units are only available to certain races. The fact that you are trying to combine them seems like bad design to me. Seems like they would be more like subclasses with a different `unitName` property or something along those lines.

Comment: The example in my question might be flawed, but keep in mind that *Archer* and *Crossbowman* are just textual names for the exact same unit in database. This same distance unit is available for both races, it just has different names according to player language and race, which is basically translation. I will consider editing my question to use better examples if the confusion persists.

Comment: Anyway, the RPG is just a very simple and pure example invented to simplify my real use case. In real world, I could be ending up with a dozen languages, even more "races" and even more "unit" types. I cannot simply declare subclasses. That's why I need a maintainable, lasting and Symfonycal solution. (:

Comment: Well in that case it could still be a property of each instance. Im not sure why you would want involve this concept in the i18n/l10n layer. But maybe im thinking wrongly.

Comment: Symfony got a Translation services http://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html you will write `unit.fr.yaml` and `unit.en.yaml`